# Как с помощью wp query фильтровать товары по индивидуальным атрибутам woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, атрибуты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я получаю все эти атрибуты выгрузкой из мой склад, Имя атрибута и значение кириллические. Ещё все атрибуты индивидуальные

Когда пытаюсь отфильтровать по атрибуту ничего не получаю. Оно в общем то логично. Я не знаю как правильно составить $args для wp_query для работы с атрибутами, и тем более не знаю как к их определять по ключу

```
                  Array
                  (
                    [post_type] => product
                    [tax_query] => Array
                  (
                  [0] => Array
                    (
                       [taxonomy] => pa_Бренд
                       [field] => slug
                       [terms] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => ISB
                    )
                  )
```

Может есть плагин транслитерации для названия атрибута, если кто знает что подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Вроде нашёл рабочее решение

```
// Set custom attribute name and value to search for
$attribute_name  = 'color';
$attribute_value = 'green';

$serialized_value = serialize( 'name' ) . serialize( $attribute_name ) . serialize( 
'value' ) . serialize( $attribute_value ); // extended version: $serialized_value = 
serialize( $attribute_name ) . 'a:6:{' . serialize( 'name' ) . serialize( 
$attribute_name ) . serialize( 'value' ) . serialize( $attribute_value ) . serialize( 
'position' );
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'post_status'    => 'any',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby'        => 'title',
     'order'          => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_product_attributes',
            'value'   => $serialized_value,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
    ),
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    $loop->the_post();
    // do stuff here... e.g. get_the_ID()
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```